# Array can not add integer

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I tried to add elements to the array,but when I tried to, it showed array is null. I was adding an integer to the array from first element, but still got the problem.Can anyone advise?

```
class unorderedArray
{
    public int[] itemArray=null ;
    private int numElements=0;
    private int maxElements=0;
    public unorderedArray(int max)
    {
        maxElements = max;
       int[] itemArray=new int[maxElements]  ;
    }
    public int[] getItemArray()
    {
        return itemArray;
    }
    public bool addLast(int item)
    {
        if (numElements < maxElements)
        {
            itemArray[numElements] = item;
            numElements++;

        }

        return true;
    }
}


    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        unorderedArray aa = new unorderedArray(60);
        aa.addLast (4);
        aa.addLast(5);
        aa.addLast(6);
        aa.addLast(8);
        aa.addLast(90);
        aa.addLast(12);
        aa.addLast(77);
        aa.printList();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `int[] itemArray=new int[maxElements]  ;` with `itemArray=new int[maxElements]  ;`

Comment: so how to avoid of fix it under C#?

Comment: Just remove `int[]` from `int[] itemArray=new int[maxElements]  ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redeclaring the array thereby making it local which should not be so
This

```
public unorderedArray(int max) {
     maxElements = max; 
     int[] itemArray=new int[maxElements] ;
}
```

Should be

```
 public unorderedArray(int max) {
     maxElements = max; 
     itemArray=new int[maxElements] ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, thanks!

Comment: sorry for the delay, accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] itemArray=null ; //   <============== THIS

public unorderedArray(int max)
{
    maxElements = max;
   int[] itemArray=new int[maxElements]  ; // <=== AND THIS ...
}
```

... `itemArray` are not the same.

If you write `int[] itemArray ...` you are declaring a local variable that hides the class field.

Just remove the "int[]" from "int[] itemArray..." inside the constructor.

Unrelated: Please stick to the convention to name classes in CamalCase. => "UnorderedArray"